# C++ Scrolling Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays

In my program I'm trying to make a scrolling char array, I have the part that allows it to scroll but how can I make it where when it goes off the map, instead of going down a line, it resets. You might have to try out my code to see what I mean. Also, have can I make it where the outline box doesn't move? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

char movingPicture[6][55];

void text(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int AxisX = 0;
    memcpy (movingPicture, picture, sizeof(picture));
    while(true)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 55; x++) {
                text(AxisX+x, 5+y, 15); cout << movingPicture[y][x]; }
            }
            AxisX++;
            Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`text(AxisX+x, 5+y, 15); cout << movingPicture[y][x];`

How about trying

`text( (AxisX+x) % windowWidth, 5+y, 15); cout << movingPicture[y][x];`

where `windowWidth` is the number of characters displayable on a line of your window? This should result in the image rolling from left to right and so on...

Comment: Thank you, everything works perfectly. Brilliant idea of code FYI!

Comment: Yes :) remains the second question of fixing the envelop

Answer (score 0):

For this program you are using the windows.h library, which is not fully recommended as the code cannot be compiled on a Linux or Mac machine, I couldn't try :(

I don't know much about text interfaces, but I know that kind of things (moving text and stuff) is usually solved using NCurses library, which is also multi-platform.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to take a different approach here, and I suggest doing something similar to how 3D graphics do this type of operation.

Since you don’t want the box to move and you don’t want this sliding down, you should not write to different positions each time. It is sliding down the screen (and leaving garbage in its wake) because of `AxisX+x`. Instead of scrolling where the output goes, you need to scroll the output itself.

I have made an example that does this. First, it writes the picture to a buffer of the same size, but offset along AxisX (which I renamed to AxisOffset for clarity). This will make the image scroll, but keep the output in the same place.

Second, an additional loop around the data conditionally fills in cells of the output buffer with non-space cells of a second frame image. This ensures the frame is drawn overtop the image.

Aside from my console cursor annoyingly bouncing around, which I believe is my console emulator's fault, this works as you requested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int yMax = 6;
int xMax = 55;

char picture[6][55] = {
    "                                                      ",
    "         .-.   .-.     .--.                           ",
    "        | OO| | OO|   / _.-'    .-.   .-.  .-.        ",
    "        |   | |   |   \\  `-.    '-'   '-'  '-'       ",
    "        '^^^' '^^^'    `--'                           ",
    "                                                      "
};
char frame[6][55] = {
    "======================================================",
    "x                                                    x",
    "x                                                    x",
    "x                                                    x",
    "x                                                    x",
    "======================================================"
};
char buffer[6][55];

void text( int, int, int );

int main( )
{
    int AxisOffset = 30;
    while( true )
    {
        // Fill the buffer with scrolling image
        for ( int x = 0; x <= ( xMax - AxisOffset - 1 ); x++ )
        {
            for ( int y = 0; y < xMax; y++ )
            {
                buffer[y][x + AxisOffset] = picture[y][x];
            }
        }
        for ( int x = ( xMax - AxisOffset ); x < xMax; x++ )
        {
            for ( int y = 0; y < xMax; y++ )
            {
                buffer[y][x - ( xMax - AxisOffset )] = picture[y][x];
            }
        }

        // Conditionally overlay the frame on top
        for ( int y = 0; y < yMax; y++ )
        {
            for ( int x = 0; x < xMax; x++ )
            {
                if( frame[y][x] != ' ' )
                    buffer[y][x] = frame[y][x];
            }
        }

        // Flip buffer, essentially
        for ( int y = 0; y < yMax; y++ )
        {
            for ( int x = 0; x < xMax; x++ )
            {
                text( x, 5 + y, 15 );
                cout << buffer[y][x];
            }
        }
        AxisOffset++;
        Sleep( 50 );
        if( AxisOffset == xMax )
        {
            AxisOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}

void text( int x, int y, int color )
{
    COORD cPos;
    cPos.X = x;
    cPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), cPos );
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), color );
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting this wouldn't be hard to generalize, but that's probably getting into where you'd rather be looking into a library that does this.